# Scala : simulate Lotto number generator in Range 1 to 45

Tags: scala, scala-collections

The following is an imperative solution to a simulation of a Number Lottery from the Range 1 to 45, each time we generate a number n1 the number is removed from the set of possible numbers.

**Is it possible to achieve the same in a more functional way ? i.e using map,filter etc**

```
def getNumbers :Array[Int] = {

        val range = 1 to 45
        var set = range.toSet

        var resultSet:Set[Int] = Set()
        var current: Int = 0

        while(resultSet.size <  5 ){
            current = Random.shuffle(set).head // pick the head of the shuffled set
            set -= current
            resultSet += current
        }

        resultSet.toArray
    }
```

**"edit"**

An example pick 3 numbers from the Range 1 to 5

```
Original Set is {1,2,3,4,5}
{1,2,3,4,5} shuffle(1) picked at random 3
{1,2,4,5}     shuffle(2) picked at random 2
{1,4,5}       shuffle(3) picked at random 4
original Set becomes {1,5}

numbers picked {3,2,4}
```

each shuffle randomizes a different SET ! => different probabilities

**I would like to see a functional "method" with 5 shuffles not 1 shuffle !**

Comment: Sorry, but the assumption that a different ordering affects the probability doesn't hold. The functional solution is as you would find it described in a basic book on statistics. Your additional restriction, or simulation would simulate the behaviour of a drawing without abstracting enough to be a real functional solution.

Comment: not the order, the size is different, its reduced by one after each shuffle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would simulate the behaviour you wanted:

Draw one, reshuffle data left, draw one and so on.

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def draw(count: Int, data: Set[Int]): Set[Int] = {

  @tailrec
  def drawRec( accum: Set[Int] ) : Set[Int] =  
    if (accum.size == count ) 
      accum
    else 
      drawRec( accum + Random.shuffle( (data -- accum).toList ).head )

  drawRec( Set() )      
}
```

Example

```
scala> draw(5, (1 to 45).toSet)
res15: Set[Int] = Set(1, 41, 45, 17, 22)

scala> draw(5, (1 to 45).toSet)
res16: Set[Int] = Set(5, 24, 1, 6, 28)
```

Answer (score 7):

Sure, it's possible. The collections API has everything you need. What you're looking for is `take`, which will take the first `n` elements of the collection, or as many elements as the collection has if there are less than `n`.

```
Random.shuffle(1 to 45).take(5).toArray
```

Comment: each time i need to reduce the set by the previous number generated so this simple solution is not correct 100%

Comment: @firephil What do you mean? The collection contains no duplicates, so it's impossible to select the same element twice.

Comment: the propabilities are not the same though, imagine a real lottery, when you generate a number this number is taken out from the Set of possible numbers (1 shuffle vs 5 suffles)

Comment: The number *is* taken out here. You can't select the same number twice. The only difference is that instead of taking out five numbers one at a time, I'm taking out five numbers all at once. Which really, is no different.

Comment: The above code replaces `getNumbers` entirely. There is no need for re-shuffling, and re-drawing. If you somehow think it will pick some number twice, please, try it and get back to me at the end of eternity when it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72952/discussion-between-firephil-and-m-z).

Answer (score 1):

I am with m-z on this, however if you REALLY want the functional form of a constant reshuffle, then you want something like this:

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.annotation.tailrec

val initialSet = 1 to 45

def lottery(initialSet: Seq[Int], numbersPicked: Int): Set[Int] = {
  @tailrec
  def internalTailRec(setToUse: Seq[Int], picksLeft: Int, selection: Set[Int]):Set[Int]= {
    if(picksLeft == 0) selection
    else {
      val selected = Random.shuffle(setToUse).head
      internalTailRec(setToUse.filter(_ != selected), picksLeft - 1, selection ++ Set(selected))
    }
  }
  internalTailRec(initialSet, numbersPicked, Set())
}

lottery(initialSet, 5)
```

Comment: Yes that is what i meant, i was thinking to use recursion with a helper inner function but i wondered if a simpler solution-trick existed...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @m-z's solution as well and agree with his reasoning about the probability. Reading the source for `Random.shuffle` is probably a worth while exercise.

Each iteration removes an element from `range` and adds it to the accumulator `acc` which is similar to your imperative approach except that we are not mutating collections and counters.

```
import scala.util.Random._
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def getNumbers(): Array[Int] = {
  val range = (1 to 45).toSeq
  @tailrec
  def getNumbersR(range: Seq[Int], acc: Array[Int], i: Int): Array[Int] = (i, range(nextInt(range.size))) match{
    case (i, x) if i < 5 => getNumbersR(range.filter(_ != x), x +: acc, i + 1)
    case (i, x)          => acc
  }
  getNumbersR(range, Array[Int](), 0)
}

scala> getNumbers
res78: Array[Int] = Array(4, 36, 41, 20, 14)
```

Comment: Interesting approach, with pattern matching and recursion